# How to write much less than symbol (<<) in plotmath in R?

Tags: r, symbols, equation, plotmath

I'm trying to write the << symbol in R but I'm not succeeding. Any tips?

```
plot(expression(alpha<1))
```

[image]

```
plot(expression(alpha<<1))

Error: unexpected input in "plot(expression(alpha<<"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using unicode

```
plot(1, 1, xlab = bquote(alpha~"\u226A"~1))
```

Comment: why does "bquote" change the behaviour of unicode in the plot window compared to just plain unicode? Eg; `plot(1:3, main = '\u226A')` gives me a fine little square, while adding bquote fixes it right up.

Comment: @Oliver It may be an issue related to the encoding settings in your system

Comment: `bquote` changes the behavior of `alpha`, as far as I can tell not of the unicode character. @Oliver might be having a missing (not installed) fonts problem.

Comment: It's interesting as `'\u226A'` works fine in the console, but fails in the plot window. Windows OS problems maybe.

Comment: I think you may find that `bquote` forces use of the Symbol font, whereas you get the default font when it's not clearly intended as `expression`-class.

Comment: Note that the plot method being called seems to be different than base graphics: `plot(expression(alpha<1))` gives
`Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : invalid first argument`

Answer (score 2):

This is the closest I am so far, how does this work for you?

```
plot(
        x = 1:10,
        y = 1:10,
        main = expression(paste(alpha, "<<", 1))
)
```